# cipher encryption decryption logic

Tags: c, encryption, decode

i found lot of solution but no one is faster 
here is the problem...

MR 'A' and MR 'B' are friends. 
They want to encrypt their conversation . So they invent a new cipher. 
Every message is encoded to its binary representation 
Then it is written down K times, shifted by 0,1,⋯,K−1 bits.

If B=1001010 and K=4 it looks so:

```
`1001010   
  1001010  
   1001010 
    1001010`
```

and then we perform the xor operation and we get

```
    1001010   
     1001010  
      1001010 
       1001010
   --------------
    1110100110 (ENCODED MESSAGE SEND TO B)
```

now then this encoded message is given to the receiver(MR 'B') with the following information

1) number of bits in original string(i.e 7 in our example)

2) number of shifts we have performed in original string (here 4)

3) the encoded string(here 1110100110)

MR 'B' HAS TO FIND THE ORIGINAL STRING THAT IS 1001010

please help me in logic that how can i find the original string i am MR 'B'

Comment: Have you tried something that you're having trouble implementing, or do you just want someone to just tell you an answer?

Comment: Why do you want to work in this field if you have no interest in this kind of problem?

Comment: i have tried but my solution take O(n^2) time @stvcisco

Comment: @Harish: The same question applies.If you have no interest in solving problems like this (given that you haven't explained *any* kind of approach you might have onsidered), why study this field? You're not going to enjoy working in it.

Comment: @KerrekSB i am new in coding and i have solved but it does not work for large input. so here i hoping some new ideas

Comment: @Harish: That's something you should say in your question. That's actually a completely different question now. Say what you have done and how it works, and say at what exact point it breaks. Then we can provide some actual, specific help.

Comment: yeah i think so. but now my problem is solved thanks everyone and @KerrekSB  thanks for valuable advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, though this belongs on math.stachexchange.com

First, let's note that xor will be `1` if the number of `1`s is odd, otherwise `0`.

So, we can work backwards:

```
???????
 ???????
  ???????
   ???????
1110100110
```

The first one is `1`, so there must be an odd number of `1`s, and there's only one space, so it must be `1`! We can copy it out to the rest:

```
1??????
 1??????
  1??????
   1??????
1110100110
```

The second one says there's an odd number of `1`s, so the space must be `0`:

```
10?????
 10?????
  10?????
   10?????
1110100110
```

The third is the same, so we need to add another `0`:

```
100????
 100????
  100????
   100????
1110100110
```

The fourth number is `0`, so we'll need to add a `1` to make the number of `1`s even:

```
1001???
 1001???
  1001???
   1001???
1110100110
```

And so on:

```
10010??
 10010??
  10010??
   10010??
1110100110

100101?
 100101?
  100101?
   100101?
1110100110

1001010
 1001010
  1001010
   1001010
1110100110
```

And voila!

Note that it's actually safe to do this:

```
1001010
 100101 0   \
  10010 10  |--- Ignorable bits
   1001 010 /
1110100
```

because you can use the same method to derive the same information.

Comment: @Harish no problem. I found it interesting myself, so I'm working on a Haskell solution. Thanks!